# Overlapping labels in aster plot

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, aster

We have a strange issue of overlapping labels in the aster plot d3 chart. We have used the d3 chart library & reference of http://bl.ocks.org/bbest/2de0e25d4840c68f2db1
In below image, 0.02% overlaps 2.91% pie.

To plot the polyline and label, I have referred http://bl.ocks.org/dbuezas/9306799

[image]

Comment: You're copy/pasting references to charts that work. Please, copy/paste the link to **your** chart. Otherwise, how do you expect we to help? Have in mind that the solution for your problem is an *ad hoc* one.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado You can have a look here http://cdpn.io/v/WpLXgd

Comment: @ParthVyas Wait a minute, just now I'm seeing that **you're not** the OP. Is this OP's code?

Comment: Yes @GerardoFurtado

Answer (score 1):

Warning: this is an *ad hoc* solution.

Using the index of the problematic label (in the CodePen you shared, it's 6) you can move everything, texts and polylines, a little bit up or down. In this case, down:

```
pos[1] = index === 6 ? pos[1] + 12 : pos[1];
outerArcCen[1] = index === 6 ? outerArcCen[1] + 10 : outerArcCen[1];
```

Here is the result: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YZgXxa?editors=0010

Comment: I need a solid solution, where I can detect which labels are overlapping